# Need header node height of TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, treeview

I have an issue were i need to find the node i have my mouse over during another source drag is happening. I manage to trap the mouse location no matter the app the drag came from. anyhow from the mouse point i am able to get the item by point and i get the `TreeViewItem` perfectly. One major issue is that if the node i am dropping on is expanded the `TreeViewItem` is including all it's child visually so when checking for my `TreeViewItem` height i get height in the thousands. when it's collapse it works perfectly i get something like 200(W) x 25(H). is there a way to grab juste the header of the node size and not including all his child ?

since it can have `TreeViewItem` in a `TreeViewItem` in-definitively and that the header is technically a `TreeViewItem` I don't understand how with PARTS i can get what i am looking for since they are all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new control myself as we couldn't find any help online for this. Took about 20-25 man hours to build a new treeview. Shame that by default the winform treeview works perfectly.